# WSL - White space breaks bash command in CMD batch script

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In `test.cmd` -

```
wsl echo "Incoming File - $(printf %%q "$(wslpath -ua "%~dpnx1")")"
wsl ls -la "$(printf %%q "$(wslpath -ua "%~dpnx1")")"
pause
```

In `C:\test`, I have two files `nospace.txt` and `has space.txt`

When I drag `nospace.txt` to `test.cmd` -

```
C:\test>wsl echo "Incoming File - $(printf %q "$(wslpath -ua "C:\test\nospace.txt")")"
Incoming File - /mnt/c/test/nospace.txt

C:\test>wsl ls -la "$(printf %q "$(wslpath -ua "C:\test\nospace.txt")")"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 yvon yvon 0 Feb  2 18:09 /mnt/c/test/nospace.txt

C:\test>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I drag `has space.txt` to `test.cmd` -

```
C:\test>wsl echo "Incoming File - $(printf %q "$(wslpath -ua "C:\test\has space.txt")")"
Incoming File - /mnt/c/test/has\ space.txt

C:\test>wsl ls -la "$(printf %q "$(wslpath -ua "C:\test\has space.txt")")"
ls: cannot access '/mnt/c/test/has\ space.txt': No such file or directory

C:\test>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It seems WSL does not appreciate escapes for white spaces. Why?

Comment: `printf %q` is only relevant if `wsl` *starts a shell*, for which escaping prepares the content. If it merely passes through a literal argument vector, there's no shell unless any code explicitly starts one, thus nothing to read and reverse that escaping. (Even then, `printf %q` is only safe when there not only *is* a shell, but when that shell is *guaranteed to be the same shell*; bash's printf %q can, with some inputs, generate outputs that cannot be correctly parsed by a baseline-standard `/bin/sh`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot. Is there any comprehensive documentation about escapes in WSL? I tried but did not find any that explains and clarifies what you have said.

Comment: I don't have any expertise about how WSL *is* implemented, and was speaking only from knowledge of what the UNIX side looks like, which gives us only a few options about how it *could be* implemented. Your question and its answer do a lot to narrow down which of those options are actually the case.

Comment: ...that said, the Windows side looks very different -- on Windows, the `int main(int argc, char**argv)` entrypoint isn't the real one but is instead a shim provided by the standard C library, such that a program can replace it with its own; the *real* entrypoint gets an unparsed command line and can parse it however it chooses. Thus, `wsl` could be implemented to bypass the default Windows parser and pass the literal text of the command line straight to a UNIX shell if it so chose. (Whereas on UNIX, that's the real interface; programs *only* see a list of already-parsed C strings).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `printf`. Don't escape the file name at all.

```
wsl echo "Incoming File - $(wslpath -ua "%~dpnx1")"
wsl ls -la "$(wslpath -ua "%~dpnx1")"
```

Output -

```
C:\test>wsl echo "Incoming File - $(wslpath -ua "C:\test\has space.txt")"
Incoming File - /mnt/c/test/has space.txt

C:\test>wsl ls -la "$(wslpath -ua "C:\test\has space.txt")"
-rwxrwxrwx 1 yvon yvon 0 Feb  2 18:09 '/mnt/c/test/has space.txt'
```

Comment: This smells like a common place where people get tripped up -- thinking that they need to make `echo ...some command...` output line up with the command they would run without the `echo`. Because `echo` runs only after string-splitting, quote removal, glob expansion, &c., making `echo` emit the "right" thing would require making your quotes *literal* rather than *syntactic* -- which is the *wrong* thing for a correctly functioning command!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

By all means you can use `printf` with `%q` to see the escaped version of your input file argument:

```cmd
wsl printf '%%s' "Incoming File - $(printf '%%q' "$(wslpath -ua "%~f1")")"
```

However, unless you're copying and pasting it somewhere, I'm not sure why you'd need to do that, so the following should be sufficient:

```cmd
wsl printf '%%s' "Incoming File - $(wslpath -ua "%~f1")"
```

Your second command, shouldn't have any issues with the space characters, so there's no need to use `printf` or `%q`, the following should suffice:

```cmd
wsl ls -la "$(wslpath -ua "%~f1")"
```

---

*If neither of these example lines are your intention, you should consider revising your question, to make it clear what you intended to ask.*

Comment: `printf`'s first argument should always be a *format string*. If you want it to print data literally, without modification, but follow it with a newline, make that format string `%s\n`, as in `printf '%s\n' "$data"`, instead of `printf "$data"`. When you substitute data into the format-string position without knowing whether that data will contain literal backslashes or `%` characters, results are unpredictable.